# как вернуть return коллекцию с пагинацией через resource Laravel?

Tags: laravel

если просто вернуть

```
    return $user->orders()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

то коллекция с пагинацией будет, а когда пройдет через Resource, то получается объект без пагинации

```
    public function index(OrderInterface $orderService): JsonResponse
    {
        $user = Auth::user()
        return response()->json([
            'orders' => OrderResource::collection($user->orders()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10))
        ]);
    }
    
    //в этом Resource есть вложенный Resource
    class OrderResource extends JsonResource
    {
        
        public function toArray($request)
        {
            return [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'customer' => $this->customer
                'products' => OrderProductResource::collection($this->products),
            ];
        }
    }
    
    class ProductResource extends JsonResource
    {
        
        public function toArray($request)
        {
            return [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'purchase_price' => $this->purchase_price,
                'price' => $this->price,
                'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            ];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public function index(): JsonResponse
            {
                
    $user = Auth::user()
            return response()->json([
                'orders' => OrderResource::collection($user->orders()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10))
->response()->getData()
            ]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

что бы нормально вывести пагинацию надо делать

```php
return OrderResource::collection($user->orders()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10));
```

по другому всегда без пагинации поидеи будет

Comment: у меня же так само сделано это не сработает

Comment: @prog-ramm  у тебя завёрнуто в response()->json()

Comment: lxShaDoWxl
дело не в этом, решение я уже ответил посмотри